# Using complex analysis, calculate $I_m = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{dx}{1+x+x^2+\cdots+x^{2m}}$ for $I_2$ and $I_3$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

**Question:**

> Using complex variables, calculate $I_m = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{dx}{1+x+x^2+\cdots+x^{2m}}$ for $I_2$ and $I_3$.

**Attempt:**

With some help, I have determined that the integral is the reciprocal of the geometric series, so that for $I_2$ and $I_3$, we really have
\begin{align*}
I_2 &= \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1-x}{1-x^5}dx \\
I_3 &= \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1-x}{1-x^7}dx.
\end{align*}
But here, I am stuck on how to proceed.

**Notes:**

I've been told that generally for odd integers $n > 2$,
$$ \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1-x}{1-x^n} dx = \frac{\pi}{n} \cdot \cot \frac{\pi}{2n} \cdot \sec \frac{\pi}{n} $$
although I am having just as much trouble working out this solution from my work above.

Comment: Use residues on a path that follows the real axis and loops around the upper half plane.

Comment: Taking @copper.hat's comment a step further, the singularities are roots of 1. You can even use partial fraction decomposition to make it more explicit.

Comment: Don't the singularities need to lie inside the contour to use the residue approach? If the singularities are the roots of 1, then don't they lie ON the contour?

Comment: @flapjackery No singularity can be on the real line. Look at the original equation! You only need 6 out of the 7 roots of 1. Can you guess which 6? To understand why the last of the 7 roots is not relevant look what happens in the numerator.